# Constraint the number of rows containing the same value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, rows

I have a table that looks somewhat like this

```
CREATE TABLE shift (
    shift_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    week_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    start_time DATETIME
);
```

Now I want to limit the number of rows that can have the same start_time. For example I want there to be a maximum number of two rows that can be inserted for any given start_time. Is it possible to do this with some sort of constraint? If not, how do I accomplish it then?

Comment: I think you need a trigger. Before insert you count how many rows there are already with that start_time and if the total is equal to 2 you don't insert it.

Comment: Can be done with an extra column ('seq') and a constraint (seq between 0 AND 1) and a unique index on {start_time,seq}. The caller that inserts a row still has to check the validity of the seq that he uses, but in the "trigger case" the caller also has to deal with inserts failing (because of the trigger firing at him).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a trigger function for that. Have that trigger fire each time you insert a value and when the number of records exceeds your limit, either ignore the insert or throw exception (but I don't think MySQL can do that).

More on the subject here: [MySQL Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html)